# angular js order of execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular, I'm trying to define module inside one of js files, and I felt that angular is processing my dom right away, where the `var app = angular.module("myApp", []);` will be defined at a later stage inside `Shell` or one of it's modules.

I tried with regular script tag but had errors, and I assumed if I inject this later once my dom is ready and then I instantiate modules inside `Shell`. please guide.

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     inject();
     new Shell();
});

function inject() {
    var ng = document.createElement('script');
    ng.src = "js/api/angular.js";
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    scripts.parentNode.insertBefore(ng, scripts);
}
```

inside Shell

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
            $scope.author = {
                "name": "My name",
                "title": "Developer",
                "company": "my company"
            }
        });
```

my html is

```
 <div id="result" ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
            <p>{{author.title + ", " + author.company}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How should I address this that angular waits a bit before it lets me define my modules.

Comment: read docs on how to manually bootstrap angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that angular also listens to `DOMContentLoaded` and once it is fired it looks for module called `myApp`, because you specified it in `ng-app="myApp"` directive. If you want to change this behaviour you should [bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) angular yourself. In your case you need to remove `ng-app="myApp"` from your `div` and add `angular.bootstrap(..., ['myApp']);` to your `Shell()` constructor after you defined module and defined all services, directives, controllers and other module related stuff, since after module is bootstrapped you will not be able to do it any longer.

**HTML**

```
<div id="result" ng-cloak> 
    ...
</div>
```

**Shell**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
      ...
    });

// <= Define here all module related stuff

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('result'), ['myApp']);
```

Comment: looks promising, let me try :)

Comment: @user2727195 for sure :)

Comment: question, there's a side effect, I see the curly brackets/templates for a while before it gets replaced, is there a a feature in angular to tackle such effects

Comment: try to place `ng-cloak` directive on your div. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: please also look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941124/angular-data-binding-with-passed-params