# angular data binding with passed params

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Furthering my project but having a hiccup with databinding.

the change in my data is not getting reflected on the DOM

I've a constructor function inside JS function/object.

```
constructor: function() {
    var self = this;
    var navigation = angular.module("navigation", []);
    navigation.controller("ProductIDsController", function($scope) {
        $scope.productIds = self.productIds;
    });
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('navigation'), ['navigation']);
}
```

and product id's are defined on the same level

```
productIds: ["abc", "xyz", "test"], //DOM gets populated from this array via angular

init: function(productIds) {
    console.log(this.productIds); // displays ["abc", "xyz", "test"]
    this.productIds.push("another item"); //this didn't work on the dom either
    this.productIds = productIds; //I changed the productId's by passing another array
    console.log(this.productIds); //the array got changed but DOM is still the same, 
}
```

HTML

```
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul data-ng-controller="ProductIDsController">
            <li data-ng-repeat="productId in productIds">{{productId}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Initially the DOM gets populated by the given array, but it's not changing after I pass in another array. how can I have data bind productId's in the given scenario?

Edit: JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/casadev/n50ecw5m/

Comment: it is not being changed because the productsIds array is outside the angular scope.

Comment: I guess the arrays are passed by reference, any change in the array should be reflected there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the value outside of scope, you have to call `$scope.$apply()` explicitly.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/qv31awmq/2/

```
puremvc.define({
    name: "modules.search.view.components.Navigation",

    constructor: function () {
        var self = this;
        var navigation = angular.module("navigation", []);
        navigation.controller("ProductIDsController", function ($scope) {
            self.$scope = $scope;
            $scope.productIds = self.productIds;
        });
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('navigation'), ['navigation']);
    }
}, {
    delegate: null,
    $scope: null,
    productIds: ["abc", "xyz", "test"],

    init: function (productIds) {
        var self = this;
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941124/angular-data-binding-with-passed-params/25941351#25941351
        self.productIds.length = 0;
        angular.forEach(productIds, function (entry) {
            self.productIds.push(entry);
        });
        self.$scope.$apply();
    }
}, {});

var nav = new modules.search.view.components.Navigation();
nav.init(['foo', 'bar']);
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to angular, can you please help in the above scenario on where and how I do write this line

Comment: do you have jsfiddle?

Comment: a better approach is to wrap the code making change outside of the angular scope in a $timeout with no interval set. This is the recommend way to get a digest to run after change outside scope, in a safe manner.

Comment: @Kechol sorry this, one http://jsfiddle.net/casadev/n50ecw5m/1/ (didn't instanitate the object - fixed), anyway the above url was set as base as well

Comment: awesome work, you've helped me to integrate puremvc with angular :)

Comment: @Kechol quick question in context of other data types, for instance, for String I can call String.replace function, but it's not possible for simple data types like int, float. The workaround I can think of that is always store their values in an object. Any other idea you might have? please comment.

Answer (score 2):

You're running into a classic Javascript mistake, nothing to do with AngularJS. In Javascript, arrays and objects are always passed by reference. Assume the following:

```
this.productIds = [1,2,3]
$scope.productIds = this.productIds;
```

This will make an array, let's call it "A". It will then put a reference to that array in this.productIds and $scope.productIds.

If you now do this:

```
this.productIds = [4,5,6];
console.log(this.productIds);
console.log($scope.productIds);
```

then you will get:

```
[4,5,6]
[1,2,3]
```

Why? Because setting `this.productIds` doesn't change the array. It changes which array `this.productIds` POINTS TO.

There are a lot of options for fixing this. Here's a quick hack:

```
this.productIds.length = 0; // Truncate the existing array instead of making a new one
angular.forEach(productIds, function(entry) {
    this.productIds.push(entry); // Copy the elements into our existing array
});
```

This isn't necessarily the most efficient, but it'll show you exactly what's going on.

Comment: I even tried to change the existing array, inside the init function but no change in the DOM this.productIds.push("another item");

Comment: That's still the right way to do it. You just need to use it in conjunction with @kechol's comment below about calling $scope.$apply() afterward. Probably you're doing this in some JS code of your own outside Angular's digest loop / watch cycle and it isn't seeing you do it. Try it - it's a 1-line code fix for a lot of "I want to love Angular but haven't converted every piece of my app yet" stuff.

Comment: awesome, I've added jsfiddle, seems I'm getting closer

Comment: I know puremvc could be daunting but I've updated the fiddle with the $scope approach, do you guys approve this? http://jsfiddle.net/casadev/n50ecw5m/5/

Comment: Thanks Chad, great help

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that would be to use a service to broadcast changes in productIds.

```
navigation.factory('ProductSvc', 
['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        productIds : [],
        changeProductIds: function(newIds){
            this.productIds = newIds
            $rootScope.$broadcast('changeIds');
        }
    }
}])
```

Controller linked to service :

```
navigation.controller("ProductIDsController", ['ProductSvc'], 
function($scope, productSvc) {
    ...
    $scope.$on('changeIds', function() {
            $scope.productIds = ProductSvc.productIds;
    })
}
```

Change your productId via the service (in a controller which handles user input for example)

```
ProductSvc.changeProductIds(newIds)
```